# How to use vtkInformation objects in VTK?

Tags: python, mapping, metadata, vtk

I am trying to pass some extra information (string data) in a [vtkMultiBlockDataSet](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMultiBlockDataSet.html) using its meta data [vtkInformation](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInformation.html) container. I have problems retrieving the data from the information object. The following code in python shows the problem:

```
import vtk
from vtk.util import keys

mb = vtk.vtkMultiBlockDataSet()
mb.SetBlock(0, vtk.vtkPolyData())

metaData = mb.GetMetaData(0)
key = keys.MakeKey(keys.StringKey, "Key", "x")
metaData.Set(key, "Value")

# Going to some other place in space and time    

key2 = keys.MakeKey(keys.StringKey, "Key", "x")
print metaData.Get(key2)
```

The `print` in the last line prints `None`.

How is it possible for me to retrieve the value of `Key` from the information container without using **exactly** the same key? (Using `key` in the last line above, prints the correct value)

Comment: Not possible no, you should store your keys somewhere or use vtkFieldData instead

Comment: Have you read these VTK pipeline primers ([primer 1](https://blog.kitware.com/a-vtk-pipeline-primer-part-1/) and [primer 2](https://blog.kitware.com/a-vtk-pipeline-primer-part-2/))? In one of the examples, they create the key outside the class scope and refer to that instance when they need it. So it seems not to be possible.

Comment: @normanius Yes I read both of them and also thought that it is not possible. The hint from Mathieu was good. I am now using vtkFieldData to pass information through the vtk pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mathieu and @normanius pointed out: It is not possible. Instead [vtkFieldData](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkFieldData.html) can be used to transfer information through the vtk pipeline.